# Error in colnamesInt(i, unname(on), check_dups = FALSE) : argument specifying columns specify non existing column(s): cols[1]='ID_REF'

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, statistics

I have two files, `dat` (`samp.matrix` is its data matrix) and its corresponding annotation file `ann`. I removed the outliers in `samp.matrix` and now want to update `ann` (as `ann.filtered`) by remove the corresponding outliers. How do I update `ann`?

```
samp.matrix <- data.matrix(dat[, (3:ncol(dat))])

# Remove Outlier(s) 
samp.matrix <- samp.matrix[, -(grep(names(outlier), colnames(samp.matrix)))]

# Eliminating probes with rowMeans less than 0 on a log2 scale
dat.fil <- subset(samp.matrix, log2(rowMeans(samp.matrix)) > 0)
removed <- nrow(samp.matrix) - nrow(dat.fil)

# Eliminate probes with rowMeans less than 3 on a log2 scale
dat.filtered <- subset(dat.fil, rowMeans(dat.fil) > 3)
dat.filtered <- as.data.frame(dat.filtered)
removed  <- nrow(dat.fil) - nrow(dat.filtered)


# Update annotation file
ID_REF <- rownames(ann)
ann <- cbind(ID_REF, ann)
rownames(ann) <- NULL
ann <- ann %>%  as.data.table()
dat.filtered <- dat.filtered %>%  as.data.table() 
ann.filtered <- ann[dat.filtered, on=.("ID_REF")] %>%
```

select(ID_REF, Gene.title, Gene.symbol)

> Error in colnamesInt(i, unname(on), check_dups = FALSE) :    argument
> specifying columns specify non existing column(s): cols[1]='ID_REF'

`dat`

| ID_REF | IDENTIFIER | GSM97800 | GSM97804 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1007_s_at | MIR4640 | 4701.5 | 4735.0 |
| 1053_at | RFC2 | 282.7 | 347.9 |
| 117_at | HSPA6 | 769.6 | 287.9 |
| 121_at | PAX8 | 1616.3 | 1527.2 |

`dat.filtered`

| ID_REF | IDENTIFIER | GSM97800 | GSM97804 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1007_s_at | MIR4640 | 4701.5 | 4735.0 |
| 1053_at | RFC2 | 282.7 | 347.9 |

`ann`

| ID_REF | Gene.title | Gene.symbol | Gene.ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1007_s_at | microRNA 4640//discoidin domain receptor | MIR4640//DDR1 | 100616 |
| 1053_at | replication factor C subunit 2 | RFC2 | 5982 |
| 117_at | heat shock protein family A (Hsp70) | HSPA6 | 3310 |
| 121_at | paired box 8 | PAX8 | 7849 |

**Expected output**
`ann.filtered`

| ID_REF | Gene.title | Gene.symbol | Gene.ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1007_s_at | microRNA 4640//discoidin domain receptor | MIR4640//DDR1 | 100616 |
| 1053_at | replication factor C subunit 2 | RFC2 | 5982 |

Answer (score 1):

As you have some common column in both dataframes, you can do a left join and then keep only columns of ann

```
library(dplyr)

#rename the first column to prevent having a blank column name in ann 
colnames(ann) <- c("ID_REF","Gene.title","Gene.symbol","Gene.ID") 

### join both dataframes keeping only rows rows avaiable from dat.filtered
### And keep only the original columns from ann
ann.filetered <- dat.filtered %>%
  left_join(ann, by=c("ID_REF","Gene.symbol","Gene.ID")) %>%
  select(ID_REF,Gene.title,Gene.symbol,Gene.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

easiest way is to join this tables
...with `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
ann <- ann %>%  as.data.table() ##convert to data.table
dat.filtered <- dat.filtered %>%  as.data.table() ##convert to data.table

ann[dat.filtered] %>% ##join
  select(ID_REF, Gene.title, Gene.symbol, Gene.ID) ##remove cols except selected
```

Comment: I tried your code but used `ann[dat.filtered] %>% select(c(ID_REF, colnames(ann)))`  instead. I got an error `Error in `[.data.table`(ann, dat.filtered) : 
  When i is a data.table (or character vector), the columns to join by must be specified using 'on=' argument (see ?data.table), by keying x (i.e. sorted, and, marked as sorted, see ?setkey), or by sharing column names between x and i (i.e., a natural join). Keyed joins might have further speed benefits on very large data due to x being sorted in RAM.`

Comment: suppouse that you forgot name first col (ID_REF) in `ann`. with proper name `ann[dat.filtered, on = 'ID_REF']`

Comment: Even after I added the colname `ID_REF`, I'm still getting an error that the colname doesn't exist. I've updated my question above.